# Will salting the ground kill insects and spiders?

Tags: entomology, arachnology

I want to kill the insects and spiders living in my egress using something non-toxic to humans, dogs. I was thinking copious amounts of salt would kill earth dwelling bugs and what appears to be ground spiders with funnel like webs. The insects seem to be majorly silverfish. I am in Missoula Montana.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think the bugs are coming from the egress. Here's an internet photo similar to my egress. The ground at the bottom is the area in question.
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the spiders will do, but salt *is* toxic for plants. In my place at least (Western Europe), usage of salt would kill the native plants and leave the ground to nettle.

Comment: The ground in question is in the egress. I want to stop the whole basement window food chain.

Comment: I have had some success with boric acid against an infestation in my bathroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dusting the area with a [diatomaceous earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth) based insecticide ought to do the trick, while being essentially non-toxic. If you want to prevent plant growth there too then of course [salt the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_the_earth).

See [Efficacy of modified diatomaceous earth on different cockroach species (Orthoptera, Blattellidae) and silverfish (Thysanura, Lepismatidae)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10340-006-0127-8)

Comment: As soon as I dumped diatomacous earth on my 5 egress windows, hundreds of millipedes, centipedes, spiders, silverfish, beetles, hornets came up out of the ground and the surrounding grass. Before that was 50lbs of salt, which didn't bother anybody. All the basement windows are beautiful white wastelands. THX @jzx :D

Comment: Hahaha, happy to be of service!